# How to create a service account with Google Drive access

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I am trying to create a service account in Google Cloud Platform that has Google Drive API access only. However, I cannot find the role at all:

[image]

Furthermore, if I create a 'general service account', then that user can add instances, etc. This has been a terrible security issue in the past, as users with that key have actually created unauthorized instances (thus the above question).

How would I create a service account that has access to Google Drive API, but **nothing** else?

Comment: Additionally, you can refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) on how to set-up a service account. Also, the [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3) that was mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: See [Domain-wide Delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106). Cloud (!) IAM does not extend to Google Drive (Workspace) and so there are no Google Drive (nor any other Workspace) roles that you can assign. It's a historical artifact. You can use OAuth 2.0 scopes to limit the Service Account.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your service account should only access google drive, in admin.google.com panel,

Security >> Advanced Settings >> Manage API client access

Under  type your service account ID and add google drive scope. You can find scopes  [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

Comment: Still, doesn't mention what specific scopes he should set. Should he set nothing and then set the scopes where you pointed?

Comment: Also, admin.google.com panel controls GWS. This question is about GCP, (console.cloud.google.com).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you enable the Google Drive API for your project. Then, you create a service account that has access to your project.

Once done, that service account should have access to all the APIs that have been enabled for your project.

To see if you have it enabled, go to:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/credentials?project=

[image]